# Can I add buttons to my text in Confluence?

Tags: button, confluence

The [Atlassian Design Product Components website tells about buttons](https://design.atlassian.com/product/components/buttons/)

[image]

Is there a way to use them in a confluence page as well?

Comment: I do not believe that Confluence has built in buttons, but there are third party add-ons that do. Alternatively you could make custom macros for buttons, that would be a free and easy option

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've added a user macro as described in my answer below.

Comment: Only possible if you are using the old server version of confluence.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little hack I just discovered. It's not ideal, but it looks pretty good in a pinch and requires no macros or anything weird.

Simply create a 1x1 table and put a link in it.  You can use a header cell or not to adjust the look:

[image]

Comment: The new interface in 2022 appears to have disabled the ability to resize the overall width of a table.  You can have a 1x1 table, but only if it's the full width of the screen https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-can-I-change-the-width-of-a-table/qaq-p/1560479

Comment: Yeah, this answer hasn't been viable for like 2 years :(

Comment: I now use images, as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74711092/736893

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add those buttons as User Macro. There is a [blog article with a step-by-step description](http://stiltsoft.com/blog/2014/03/atlassian-confluence-look-feel-tricks-creating-buttons/):

1. Goto `Confluence Admin > User Macros`
2. Add a new User Macro
3. Enter a code like this:

   ```
   ## Macro title: AUI Button
   ## Macro has a body: N
   ## @param Title:title=Title|type=string|required=true
   ## @param URL:title=URL|type=string|required=true
   <a href="$paramURL">
       <button class="aui-button aui-button-primary">
           $paramTitle
       </button>
   </a>
   ```
4. Then you can select your User Macro from the macro list and enter link name and destination.

Comment: FYI, you can't add user macros if you're using Atlassian Cloud

Answer (score 0):

Create a .png image of the button you want to use.  Load that as an image on the Confluence page, and attach a link to the image